# Spotify Play Button - autoplay?

Tags: spotify

I am trying to integrate Spotify Play Button into ThingLink Spotify tag so that when the iframe loads, it starts playing automatically. Is there a way to do that with some parameter?

The functionality would be similar to Soundcloud & Vimeo players here:
http://www.thinglink.com/scene/251225958915244034

Without the autoplay, user would have to click on Play twice, which wouldn't be that good of UX.

Thanks!
-Albert

Answer (score 0):

There is no autoplay functionality at present.

Autoplay isn't really what the Play Button is about — it's designed so people can listen to music if they want to. We don't really want to interrupt whatever the user is listening to already (be it something in Spotify, something else, or silence) without express permission to do so first.

Comment: In our case user has already taken the action of playing, i.e. clicking on the play button. But when the iframe is shown, user has to click on another play button, again. Loading the iframe as the only play button is an option, but then we cannot know when the user clicked on the play button to make the player stick.

Comment: Oh, I see - that's even more unsupported - the Spotify Play button isn't designed to be a media player to be controlled by your own UI.

Comment: The player is not in any way supposed to be controlled by our own UI - it is just revealed using our UI. We love Spotify and we believe songs from Spotify would work great on top of images so if you can suggest any way we could improve the UX, I'd love to hear that. Check this out: http://spotifymusic.tumblr.com/ .

Concerning the original question, just wanted to ask, as SoundCloud, Vimeo, Youtube aso. all have the autoplay feature in their embeds.