# Is it possible to click inside <object><embed> with .click()?

Tags: jquery, spotify

I am trying to let jQuery click on the play button of a spotify widget that is embedded on a page using the embed tag (`<embed>`).

the play button looks like this:

```
<div class="clickable play-pause-btn"></div>
```

Is this even possible?

[check it out on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Philip-Abe/pen/KVJxyZ)

Spotify apparently does not want people fiddling with its widgets, 
How about Deezer? (see [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Philip-Abe/pen/KVJxyZ))

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29005/ikenndac?tab=profile) Spotify employee [suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294494/102937) that this is an unsupported use of the player, and explains why.  I did some poking around with Google, but didn't find anything to indicate that things have changed in the last three years.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reaction! 
I was hoping there was a workaround, 
but if it is against their policies to let a script start the music, I suppose I will have to let it go.

I just can not figure out why the code I wrote does not work.
Does Deezer have the same policy? Would this be possible to achieve with a Deezer widget?